# Steps to rearrange this formula

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone explain how to rearrange this equation

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = ay-b$$

to

$$\frac{dy/dx}{y-(b/a)}=a$$

I can see that if I divide through with $y-b$ I'm nearly there, but I don't see how to end up with $y-(b/a)$ in the denominator on the left hand side.

Comment: You should use MathJax to write mathematics in this site, lest your stuff won't be properly understood:http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: The second equation is equal to $\frac{y'}{y}=b+a$, and it doesn't seem really equivalent to the original equation...

Comment: It because somebody edited the original formula using mathjax and changed it, I've changed it back now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $b=a\left(\dfrac{b}{a}\right).$  Therefore we have
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=ay-a\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)$$Factoring $a$ out we have
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=a\left(y-\frac{b}{a}\right)\implies\frac{\frac{dy}{dx}}{y-\frac{b}{a}}=a$$which is the form that you want.

Comment: That was brilliant. Thanks for taking the time to point that out!

Comment: Not a problem.  Glad it helped you out!